# Prove the transitiveness of the asymmetric part of the transitive relation. Using a set language.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

How could I prove the transitiveness of the asymmetric part of the transitive relation? Solely for the learning purposes I want to prove it using just set language, while I know how to prove it using graph and analytic languages.

Here are the only notions I want to use:

[image]

Here are the conditions of the thing I want to prove:

[image]

Here is my first step of proving that:

[image]

Why am I asking for the help? I do it because my set language skills are very poor and I would like to develop them, but I can not tackle the issue I faced here on my own.

Will be grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assume R transitive, aRb, bRc, not bRa, not cRb,
Then aRc.  If cRa, then bRa a contradiction.
Thus not cRa.
In conclusion, if R is transitive, so is $R^a.$

Use of images does cause delays and no responses.
Graphs, ie diagrams, are never a proof.
What is an analytic language?

Comment: Here are the images:https://ibb.co/fSNrkS,
https://ibb.co/mMkYzn,
https://ibb.co/cmzRKn.

Comment: Thank you, but the prove you provided I know. I am asking for another approach here. I want to prove that just by using a set language.

Comment: Some theorems cannot be proved algebracially or are more difficult if proved algebraically which need point by point proofs.